# Java: How to count the score of the word that has two identical consecutive letters into String[] array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Given a string like:

```
 "all perfect"
```

my target is to count the score of the words by characters: `a=1, b=2, c=3` etc.
but if I found two indentical consecutive letters form into the word (`ll` for `all`), the score it will be multiplicate for 2.

Now i have make this code to calculate a linear word:

```
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {

                sum += 1 + ch - 'A';

                System.out.printf("The sum of %s is %d%n", str, sum);
```

how can I count the value of the word if it is given by input? I used to split the String previously.

```
String[] arr = str.split(" ");
int sumDupicate = consecutiveLetters(arr);
```

I have some issues here when I try to do the method:

```
 public static int consecutiveLetters(String[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j;
        int sum = 0;
        char ch1, ch2;
        for (j = 1; j < arr[i].length(); j++) {
            ch1 = arr[i].charAt(j);
            ch2 = arr[i].charAt(j - 1);
            if (ch1 == ch2) {
                //obviously this sum, count is wrong
                    sum += ((int) arr[i] -96)*2;
                }
```

### EDIT:

If I have the sentence:

> aabbcc

the algorthm needs to give the score: 96
because:

```
    aabbcc = 
    double 12 * 2 = 24, 
    double it again = 24 *2 = 48 
    double it again = 48 * 2 = 96
```

a word's score is doubled for every adjacent pair of letters is contains.
I hope now is clear my request.

Comment: `I have some issues here when I try to do the method` - which are .. ?

Comment: How can count the value of the word that has two identical consecutive letters

Comment: Sorry, but without indicating any scheme for calculating the word score this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int consecutiveLetters(String[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        char ch1, ch2;
        double numberOfDuplicates = 0, word = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length()-1; j++) {
            ch1 = arr[i].charAt(j);
            ch2 = arr[i].charAt(j + 1);
            if (ch1 == ch2) {
                numberOfDuplicates++;
            }
            if(Character.isUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(j))) {
                word += (int) arr[i].charAt(j) - 64;
            } else {
                word += (int) arr[i].charAt(j) - 96;
            }
        }
        word += ((int) arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length()-1) - 96);

        if(numberOfDuplicates > 0) {
             double num = Math.pow(2, numberOfDuplicates);
             word = word * num;
        }
        sum += word;
    }
    return sum;

}
```

> Input: ["all"]
>
> Output: 25
>
> Input: ["aabbcc"]
>
> Output: 96

Comment: good works, thanks.

Comment: This is just a basic solution, you might want to test for uppercase letters, special characters etc.

Comment: sorry if I put 'all' I obtain: -71      ?!

Comment: there is something wrong into the solution

Comment: are u having the `'` ? If `arr[0] = "all"` then the sum is `25`.

Comment: I asked the method but I obtain something different?! I am in debug

Comment: can u show me how u are initizlizing ur arr.. and how u are calling this method?

Comment: in the last return if i put system.out.println I got: -71 anyway I call the method so:
`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        String[] arr = str.split(" ");
        int sumDuplicate = consecutiveLetters(arr);
        System.out.println(sumDuplicate);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161225/discussion-between-ajc-and-storecode).

Answer (score 0):

Look at having a char that keeps track of the last letter and compare it to the current letter. If they match, then do the multiplication that is needed.

Comment: but I need to have the sum of all the letters that forms the word into the array [] String

Answer (score 0):

Since you've split the array by spaces already, for each one loop through the String and compare the letter, with the next letter, and return true if found.

```
public static boolean letterDuplicate(String s) {
    boolean check = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Then do a check `if(true)`, multiply by 2.